# Shiny: Making a dynamic pulldown menu that includes an "all rows" option

Tags: r, dynamic, shiny, reactive

I am trying to make a Shiny app that will show all rows of a table, or allow the user to select a subset of rows.  Eventually there will be multiple pulldown menus, but right now I am just trying to make one work all the way through.

For some reason, the Status in the filter () statement is not found by the app.  That is probably separate from the issue of allowing all rows to appear if nothing is picked by the pulldown menu.

Any help or links to examples would be much appreciated.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Products"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel( 
      uiOutput("statusOutput"),
      sliderInput("modelInput","Model Number", 0,200,c(100,200))
     ),

    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("results")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$statusOutput <- renderUI({
    selectInput("statusInput","Status",
                sort(unique(Product_List$Status)))
  })

  filtered <- reactive ({
    if (is.null (input$statusInput)) {
      return(NULL)
    }

    Product_List %>%
      filter(Status == input$statusInput )
    })

    output$results<-renderTable({
     filtered()
      })
    }

    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks okay to me, the filter also works as expected. Try running your code with

```
Product_List = data.frame(Status=c(1,2,3,4,5))
```

---

The code below is an example of the desired behavior you describe, where all rows are selected if the user gives no input, and the dataframe is filtered otherwise. I hope this helps!

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

Product_List = data.frame(Status=c(1,2,3,4,5))

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Products"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel( 
      uiOutput("statusOutput"),
      sliderInput("modelInput","Model Number", 0,200,c(100,200))
    ),

    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("results")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$statusOutput <- renderUI({
    selectizeInput("statusInput","Status",
                sort(unique(Product_List$Status)),multiple=TRUE,options=list(placeholder="All"))
  })

  filtered <- reactive ({
    if (length(input$statusInput)==0) {
      return(Product_List)
    }

    Product_List %>%
      filter(Status %in% input$statusInput )
  })

  output$results<-renderTable({
    filtered()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  I'm still working through the reactive part but I did get the top filters to show up. Obviously I am new to this.